# Alternar Tabs no ViewPager via botão pelo fragment

Tags: java, android, viewpager

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de alternar entre as tabs pelo próprio fragment. Possuo um ViewPager com 2 tabs e gostaria de alternar via botões pois valido alguns campos antes de alternar as tabs.

Desabilitei o swipe e também a action bar para evitar que se alterne as tabs sem validar os dados de saída. Não postei código nenhum porque preciso saber apenas como chamar outra tab via botão. o resto do código é desnecessário acredito

```
 public void changePagerItem(int pageNumber) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

método implementado na classe main

```
btnFinalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ValidaPedidoAcp();
            ValidaPedidoObs();
            ValidaPedidoOpc();
            FastFoodPedidoActivity tabs = (FastFoodPedidoActivity)getActivity().getParent();
            tabs.changePagerItem(0);
        }
    });
```

método implementado no botão.... mas dá o seguinte erro

> ```
> Process: com.meuapp.example, PID: 4048
>      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void Pedidos.FastFoodPedidoActivity.changePagerItem(int)' on a null object reference
>          at Pedidos.Tabs.TabAdicionais$2.onClick(TabAdicionais.java:282)
>          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)
>          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
> ```

Comment: Se quer saber se "existe uma maneira de alternar entre tabs pelo próprio fragment", a resposta é sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só vai precisar definir um **método** em sua **activity** que mude o item do **ViewPager** e depois, realizar uma referência para a sua **activity** da qual o **fragment** está atrelado e então você terá acesso livre ao **método**.

```
// ExampleActivity() ...
public void changePagerItem(Int pageNumber) {
    yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
}

// Fragment() ...
((ExampleActivity) getActivity()).changePagerItem(3);
```

Comment: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.dev_03.sabbemobile.Telas.Pedidos.BarRestaurante.FastFood.FastFoodPedidos.FastFoodPedidoActivity.changePagerItem(int)' on a null object reference at Pedidos.Tabs.TabAdicionais$2.onClick(TabAdicionais.java:282)

Comment: dá esse erro, vários métodos de se fazer isso estão retornando esse erro de null object reference

Comment: @MarcioVieira, tentou `((FastFoodPedidoActivity)getActivity()).changePagerItem(1);`?

Comment: sim, tentei.... mesmo erro, até se usar 0

Comment: Faça o seguinte, no método `changePagerItem` print alguma coisa aleatória, se isto ocorrer sem erros, o problema é que o 'mViewPager' não está sendo referenciado, ou seja, de alguma forma, ele é nulo.

Comment: então, foi só trocar o mSectionViewPager pelo mViewPager que funcionou... Valeu pela ajuda galera